# Which version(s) of SRP are in ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006?

Tags: passwords, srp, standards

I am on the impression that [SRP](http://srp.stanford.edu/) emerges as the least uncommon and best analyzed protocol for authentication and key agreement based on a short password.

[This](http://srp.stanford.edu/doc.html#standards) states that SRP is part of IEC 11770-4, among other protocols. But no version is specified, and I've seen there's [SRP-1](http://srp.stanford.edu/design1.html), [SRP-2](http://srp.stanford.edu/design2.html), [SRP-3](http://srp.stanford.edu/design3.html), [SRP-6](http://sudis.free.fr/srp6.pdf), and the [current SRP-6a](http://srp.stanford.edu/design.html).

Hence my first question: which version(s) of SRP are in [ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec11770-4%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf)? (link is to a free preview; drafts are available [here](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/Research/Other.html) to those willing to subscribe to a mailing list, and I have yet to spot a meaningful technical difference between the October 31, 2005 draft and the real thing)

Which list of parameters and options to SRP or/and ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006 would be necessary to define implementations to the point of being secure and inter-operable?

Also: ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006 can use an Elliptic Curve setting, with (I guess) shorter cryptograms; is that the case for SRP?

---

Update: the motivation of the question is that ISO/IEC 11770-4 is an international standard, approved by a committee, which is more reassuring to a decision-maker than SRP-6a as defined by a web page than can disappear or change any second.

In a comment, [Smit Johnth](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/5102/smit-johnth) suggested [TLS-SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-SRP)/[RFC 5054](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054), which has some traction. That could be a possible choice. I'm reading it as implementing SRP-6a, despite claiming to implement SRP-6 with reference to documents predating SRP-6a. My main reservations are that TLS is a bit heavy for my application; and RFC 5054 is stuck to SHA-1, which is bad from a certification standpoint: in France, any hash less than 200 bits, or 256 bits for use after year 2020, does not match rules in section 2.3 of these [official recommendations](http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/RGS_B_1.pdf), which at least can make a prescriber less comfortable.

Comment: Since SE is already impersonal and community-oriented, could you explain, why is ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006 so interesting?

Comment: There is already TSL-SRP, what's the difference between it and ISO?

Comment: If you consider you local network secure, you can use plain text :)

Comment: There seems to be a trend of SRP-6a being misquoted as SRP-6 in standards. IEEE Std 1363.2-2008 does the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplier parameter $k$ [is different](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3509/why-does-srp-6a-use-k-hn-g-instead-of-the-k-3-in-srp-6) between SRP 6 and 6a. You can see that RFC 5054 [calculates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054#section-2.6) it using a hash of the domain parameters (modulus $N$ and generator $g$), so it is using SRP 6a, as opposed to SRP 6 where $k$ is constant.

Likewise, in section 6.2.1 of IEC 11770-4 – the October 2005 draft at least – the equivalent value $c$ is defined as a hash of the domain parameters which it calls $q$ and $g_{q-1}$, so it too is based on SRP 6a.

> Also: ISO/IEC 11770-4:2006 can use an Elliptic Curve setting, with (I guess) shorter cryptograms; is that the case for SRP?

Yes. The protocol in 6.2 is defined for either of the fields in section 5: the discrete logarithm one or the elliptic curve one.