# HMAC based challenge-response authentication

Tags: authentication, hmac

Would a challenge response HMAC authentication be secure?

i.e.

1. Client sends id
2. Server sends a challenge(32byte value)
3. Client calculates hmac_sha256 of the challenge value with its key and sends the reply
4. Server verifies the reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's as secure as a symmetric challenge-response authentication can be. Some remarks:

- In an authentication protocol, the only assurance is that the authenticated party participated in the protocol. It could well be that there's a [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
- Step 1 (sending client ID) can be coalesced into 3 if all clients have to authenticate that way regardless of ID.
- At step 2, the server's challenge should be unique and unpredictable. Making that reliable is less easy than it seems.
- At step 4, the server must be able to get or regenerate the client's key, from a database of random keys, or a master key and a key derivation function.

The big problems are

- Said database or master key could leak for the server, and poof goes all security. One good mitigation is to use a security token (HSM, Smart Card..) in the server, programmed so that it can only check the response to challenges.
- The ultimate solution from the standpoint of avoiding server leaks is when there is noting secret in there. Challenge/response replacing HMAC with a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) allows just that.
- Authentication is one thing, securing what follows next is better. That's why we have authentication-and-key-agreement protocols. Good ones resist [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
- The client's key (symmetric or asymmetric) can be compromised on the client side. A password (and proper password-based key derivation) to encipher the key-at-rest in the client might help, but is less convenient than directly using the password as an authentication mean. That's why we have [SRP and ISO/IEC 11770-4](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8567/555).

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Regarding step 2, would a cryptographically random base64 string be secure enough? Also forgot to mention that this whole thing is happening on top of HTTPS(websockets).

Comment: @ErlangWannabe: yes, a _"cryptographically random base64 string"_ will do; if it is 32-character (resp 44), it is practically as good as if it had 192 (resp.256) bits of entropy, that's fine for all purposes. Getting that on a properly running device is easy, the hard part is detecting failure (perhaps adversarially induced) leading to non-cryptographically random challenge (e.g. repeating), while not stopping operation per bad luck. "On top of HTTPS" is vague; if the server is authenticated (by way of a server certificate) and a ciphersuite immune to MitM is running, that does help.