# Diffie-Hellman based password challenge response scheme

Tags: elliptic-curves, authentication, passwords, challenge-response

A very commonly used (examples: [HTTP digest auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)/[CHAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol)/[Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Authentication)) authentication scheme is something that looks like:

**Setup.**

- Client and server both know a password $p$.

**Authentication.**

- Server sends a *random* challenge $\alpha$.
- Client computes $r = \text{KDF}(p || \alpha)$ and sends $r$ to the server.
- Server computes $r' = \text{KDF}(p || \alpha)$ and checks $r' \overset{?}{=} r$.

This scheme is also described in other questions ([example](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51931/45787)).
Now this scheme has the disadvantage that the server needs to know the plaintext password. Could we make a public-key-based scheme for challenge response authentication?

For example, we could use elliptic curve arithmetic:

**Setup.**

- Client has a secret password $p$ (with reasonable entropy) and from this derives a key  $k$ using a hash function.
- The client computes $[k]P = Q_k$ and the server will store this value as the user's public key.

**Authentication.**

- Server sends a random challenge $Q_\alpha = [\alpha]P$.
- Client computes $Q_s = [k]Q_\alpha$ and sends $Q_s$ to the server.
- The server computes $Q_s' = [\alpha]Q_k$ and checks $Q_s' \overset{?}{=} Q_s$.

Does this scheme work? Why would most systems use HMAC-based scheme instead?

Comment: If $p$ has sufficient entropy and you can derive the key $k$ in such a way that recovering $p$ from $k$ is hard, why not just use $k$ in your original protocol (with the $KDF$) instead? Does your proposed elliptic curve variant provide any additional protections that are not provided when using $k$?

Comment: Do you mean that the server stores a derived key from the user? In this case the server still needs to store a private value. If this value is breached, the attacker can authenticate as the user. In the second scheme, this is not the case. The server only stores a public value.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your use case. Typically a server stores a salted/hashed version of the password. When I try to authenticate I send the password. The server salts and hashes the password I send and compares with the saved version. If they match, I am in. An attacker stealing the salted/hashed version of the password cannot log in as me.

Comment: So this is about authentication systems like [CHAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol) and [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Authentication), both of which need the server to have a copy of the password. I would like to look if we can build something that does not have this requirement (but similar security properties).

Comment: You are aware that for practical applications you should use proper _Password Authenticated Key Exchanges_ (PAKEs)? These will yield you a shared key iff the client has the password associated to some server-side verifier.

Comment: Yeah. So this question proposes an _Augmented PAKE_ (modulo some domain separation and stuff). Didn't know about this term yet. Maybe you just answered my question. :P

Comment: @SEJPM, that is where I was going next. It has been a while since I have looked at things like SRP, but it seems very relevant here.

Comment: What does 'augmented PAKE' mean? Because this is actually just a tiny variation of [SPEKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPEKE): A general purpose "derivation" from $p$ to $k$ instead of a hash function (which probably should be specified) and using an elliptic curve instead of $\mathbb{F}_p$. So probably it should be noted, that SPEKE has weaknesses, and these are probably also present in the proposed idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, what you are trying to construct here is called an *augmented* or *asymmetric* *password-based key exchange* (aPAKE). As for your concrete construction:

> Does this scheme work?

Yes, it will be functionally correct.

Does it actually achieve the security guarantees of an aPAKE scheme? No, an attacker can look at the transcript, see $Q_s=[k]Q_a$ and knows both $Q_s$ and $Q_a$ and thus can just off-line brute-force the password.

The first (symmetric) scheme you mentioned suffers from the same problem.

> Could we make a public-key-based scheme for challenge response
> authentication?

This is what aPAKE schemes do, the most notable protocols are:

- the *Secure Remote Password Protocol* (SRP), mostly because it was first to be standardized in [RFC 2945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2945).
- [OPAQUE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/163) which is the current state-of-the-art when it comes to (simple) aPAKEs.
- If you also want to assume an auxilliary 2nd device for the user, [OpTFA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/033) is the state-of-the-art.
- If the user "only" has a device capable of running an (EC)DH key agreement (like a smartcard), then [PTR-PAKE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1099) is the best you can get.

Example implementations (in C) of OPAQUE and PTR-PAKE can be found in [libsphinx](https://github.com/stef/libsphinx).

Comment: I may add the best current symmetric PAKE later (if I can clearly identify it).